# Length extends beyond buffer error during ReadSync call in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, rtp

I'm attempting to create RTP packets for an MJPEG video.  First, I read the first 5 bytes of the file which gives me the length of the frame, and then I read the returned size.

Here is my code:

```
    while(totalSizeScanned < totalSize){

            var tmp_buf = Buffer(5)
            fs.readSync(fd,tmp_buf,totalSizeScanned,5);

            totalSizeScanned += 5;

            var stringBuffer = tmp_buf.toString("utf-8");
            this.total_len = parseInt(stringBuffer, 10);

            var frame_buf = Buffer(this.total_len);

            fs.readSync(fd, frame_buf, totalSizeScanned, this.total_len);
            file_content[frameNo] = frame_buf;

            frameNo++;
            totalSizeScanned += this.total_len;

        }
```

This is giving me a "Length extends beyond buffer" error on the second readSync call.  I don't understand why this is happening, as the size I read should be the size of the buffer.  I've been searching the docs and google for about an hour but haven't been able to find anything.  I'm new to Node so this may be trivial but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it's an offset vs. position: either start at offset 0 at the current position (null=current position), or at offset `totalSizeScanned` offset starting at position `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the bytes for the length, start at 0 in the new buffer and add in null for position

```
fs.readSync(fd, frame_buf, 0, this.total_len-5,null);
```

Comment: I've tried that before.  It's been giving an "Offset is out of bounds" error.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm getting the same error whether I set the position parameter to null or leave it out.

Comment: Setting offset to 0 is given an Offset is out of bounds error

Comment: @Wrikken because of this line `fs.readSync(fd,tmp_buf,totalSizeScanned,5);`

Comment: Ah, those bytes are _included_ in the length of the frame, not prepended?

Comment: @Wrikken - that is my guess, I've not read this spec but every other similar system has total size meaning total size.

Comment: Yeah, could be... `MJPEG` is multiple frames though... Ah well, the `length` is hardly the cause of the `offset` being out of bounds. Without an MJPEG to inspect, I bow out ;)

Comment: I've re-read the specs and the size given does not include the first 5 bytes.  So if the first 5 bytes return 3510, the first frame actually ends at 3515.

Comment: Issue was actually with the first readSync on the second loop.  Fixed it by setting by readSyncs to offset at 0, with a length of 5 or total_len.